# Phonegap application stops unexpectedly on Indigo running Android ADT 20

Tags: android, cordova, compiler-errors

I am using eclipse indigo with android ADT 20 but everytime it shows error that application stop unexpectedly.
Please any one have idea about how to use both of them with each other?
I also refer some google groupe which shows to update ecllipse and I also follow that but still not working. Thx in advance...

LOGS:

```
07-27 16:48:04.958: D/ddm-heap(217): Got feature list request
07-27 16:48:05.328: I/dalvikvm(217): Could not find method android.webkit.WebView.<init>, referenced from method org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.<init>
07-27 16:48:05.328: W/dalvikvm(217): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 3114: Landroid/webkit/WebView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;IZ)V
07-27 16:48:05.328: D/dalvikvm(217): VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0001
07-27 16:48:05.328: D/dalvikvm(217): Making a copy of Lorg/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView;.<init> code (196 bytes)
07-27 16:48:05.658: D/dalvikvm(217): GC freed 807 objects / 63672 bytes in 104ms
07-27 16:48:05.948: E/dalvikvm(217): Could not find class 'android.webkit.WebResourceResponse', referenced from method org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient.generateWebResourceResponse
07-27 16:48:05.958: W/dalvikvm(217): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 451 (Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;) in Lorg/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient;
07-27 16:48:05.958: D/dalvikvm(217): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0046
07-27 16:48:05.958: D/dalvikvm(217): Making a copy of Lorg/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient;.generateWebResourceResponse code (245 bytes)
07-27 16:48:05.958: W/dalvikvm(217): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;)
07-27 16:48:05.998: W/dalvikvm(217): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;)
07-27 16:48:06.014: W/dalvikvm(217): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;)
07-27 16:48:06.014: I/dalvikvm(217): Could not find method android.webkit.WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest, referenced from method org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest
07-27 16:48:06.014: W/dalvikvm(217): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3125: Landroid/webkit/WebViewClient;.shouldInterceptRequest (Landroid/webkit/WebView;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;
07-27 16:48:06.014: D/dalvikvm(217): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0015
07-27 16:48:06.014: D/dalvikvm(217): Making a copy of Lorg/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient;.shouldInterceptRequest code (68 bytes)
07-27 16:48:06.018: W/dalvikvm(217): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/webkit/ConsoleMessage;)
07-27 16:48:06.018: I/dalvikvm(217): Could not find method android.webkit.ConsoleMessage.message, referenced from method org.apache.cordova.CordovaChromeClient.onConsoleMessage
07-27 16:48:06.018: W/dalvikvm(217): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3084: Landroid/webkit/ConsoleMessage;.message ()Ljava/lang/String;
07-27 16:48:06.018: D/dalvikvm(217): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0000
07-27 16:48:06.028: D/dalvikvm(217): Making a copy of Lorg/apache/cordova/CordovaChromeClient;.onConsoleMessage code (56 bytes)
07-27 16:48:06.038: W/System.err(217): =====================================================================================
07-27 16:48:06.056: W/System.err(217): ERROR: plugin.xml is missing.  Add res/xml/plugins.xml to your project.
07-27 16:48:06.056: W/System.err(217): https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=incubator-cordova-android.git;a=blob;f=framework/res/xml/plugins.xml
07-27 16:48:06.056: W/System.err(217): =====================================================================================
07-27 16:48:06.056: W/ResourceType(217): No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000000
07-27 16:48:06.058: D/AndroidRuntime(217): Shutting down VM
07-27 16:48:06.058: W/dalvikvm(217): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
07-27 16:48:06.058: E/AndroidRuntime(217): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-27 16:48:06.078: E/AndroidRuntime(217): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testdemo/com.example.testdemo.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
07-27 16:48:06.078: E/AndroidRuntime(217):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
07-27 16:48:06.078: E/AndroidRuntime(217):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
07-27 16:48:06.078: E/AndroidRuntime(217):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
07-27 16:48:06.078: E/AndroidRuntime(217):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
07-27 16:48:06.078: E/AndroidRuntime(217):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-27 16:48:06.078: E/AndroidRuntime(217):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-27 16:48:06.078: E/AndroidRuntime(217):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-27 16:48:06.078: E/AndroidRuntime(217):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 16:48:06.078: E/AndroidRuntime(217):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-27 16:48:06.078: E/AndroidRuntime(217):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-27 16:48:06.078: E/AndroidRuntime(217):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-27 16:48:06.078: E/AndroidRuntime(217):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-27 16:48:06.078: E/AndroidRuntime(217): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
07-27 16:48:06.078: E/AndroidRuntime(217):  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:891)
07-27 16:48:06.078: E/AndroidRuntime(217):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1865)
07-27 16:48:06.078: E/AndroidRuntime(217):  at android.content.res.Resources.getXml(Resources.java:779)
07-27 16:48:06.078: E/AndroidRuntime(217):  at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager.loadPlugins(PluginManager.java:99)
07-27 16:48:06.078: E/AndroidRuntime(217):  at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager.init(PluginManager.java:76)
07-27 16:48:06.078: E/AndroidRuntime(217):  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.loadUrlIntoView(CordovaWebView.java:361)
07-27 16:48:06.078: E/AndroidRuntime(217):  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.loadUrl(CordovaWebView.java:314)
07-27 16:48:06.078: E/AndroidRuntime(217):  at org.apache.cordova.DroidGap.loadUrl(DroidGap.java:356)
07-27 16:48:06.078: E/AndroidRuntime(217):  at com.example.testdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
07-27 16:48:06.078: E/AndroidRuntime(217):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-27 16:48:06.078: E/AndroidRuntime(217):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
07-27 16:48:06.078: E/AndroidRuntime(217):  ... 11 more
07-27 16:48:06.098: I/dalvikvm(217): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
07-27 16:48:06.098: E/dalvikvm(217): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
07-27 16:48:08.998: I/Process(217): Sending signal. PID: 217 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Initially Which ADT version you used?

Comment: Please check Log and give me solution if you have...

Comment: Tell me you Initial ADT version? was it less than 16?

Comment: Actually I used ADT 20.0 revised...

Comment: Please see the [Markdown formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). @Coder_sLaY was nice enough to edit twice for you, and two others edited too, but it's not hard to do get things right yourself. Click the "edited .. hour ago" to see [what changes have been made](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11685657/revisions). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue occurs because the **"lib"** folder is renamed to **"libs"** now by Android People.
You need to create a `libs` folder instead of `lib` and then place your cordova.jar file there.
And as soon as we place our external jars to this "libs" folder then it will automatically be added to the build path of the application. Then run your application....
Let me know if this helps you...

Comment: After that it not shows uncaught exception but still show error that anroid.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

Comment: First Clean it... And make sure all your external libraries are in libs folder... If still you getting error than paste your new logs here....

Comment: My folder hierarchy assets->www->index.html, crodova1.9.0.js, jquery1.7.2.js and as you said in libs folder-> crodova1.9.0.jar

Comment: See in the logs it is clearly mentioned `ERROR: plugin.xml is missing.  Add res/xml/plugins.xml to your project.`. There is a plugin.xml file which you got in the phonegap package... You forgot to add that in res->xml ... Infact i think so you forgot to add the xml folder which we get along with phonegap package...

Comment: Hey that is work finely.... Thank you thank you thank you so much yar.... Thanks again....

Answer (score 1):

You should try debugging your build. See here: http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html

I would recommend downloading the android sdk examples (ie native code examples) and running them to understand how android works. This will help you in setting up phonegap (which is just a webview in an android app with a JS-Native bridge).

To get the android sdk examples you can download them through the android "sdk manager"

Comment: Actually I try that one but log not shows any error but I have surly doubt about compatibility of android ADT 20 and phonegap 2.0

Comment: I have 1.6 I think. It works with ADT20. Try getting the stacktrace via DDMS. See this: http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/07/using-ddms-to-profile-android-apps/

Comment: Actually before updation of my ADT all phonegap app work perfectly but after ADT 20 it shows error.

Comment: What api version are you building against? Its having issues with the contacts stuff. There is quite a difference with contacts between 1.6 and 2.0+

Comment: I used Android API Level 7. Actually used minimum level so it will not create any problem.

Comment: Could not find class 'android.webkit.WebResourceResponse', referenced from method org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient.generateWebResourceResponse

Comment: I have same issue some one can help me :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839836/salesforce-android-app-remote-access-application-authorization