# Phonegap Contact API Issue

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i need to fetch contact list from android device using phonegap.....i have follow this one

[PHONEGAP CONTACT API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contacts)

and wrote this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

PhoneGap Device Ready Example

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Call onDeviceReady when PhoneGap is loaded.
//
// At this point, the document has loaded but phonegap-1.0.0.js has not.
// When PhoneGap is loaded and talking with the native device,
// it will call the event 'deviceready'.
// 
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter="Bob"; 
    var fields = ["displayName", "name"];
    navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
}
 function onSuccess(contacts) {
    alert('OnSucess!');
    for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
        console.log("Display Name = " + contacts[i].displayName);
    }
}

// onError: Failed to get the contacts
//
function onError(contactError) {
    alert('onError!');
}

</script>
```

i have given this permission in my manifest

- **android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS**
- **android.permission.READ_CONTACTS**
- **android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS**

& this plugin

```
<plugin name="Contacts" value="com.phonegap.ContactManager"/>
```

i am using phonegap version 1.4.1,when i run my application always i get alert('OnError');
what should be the reason behind it? is it versioning problem?any guide is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: You'd better check out the `contactError`, `alert('onError!')` makes no sense. And any error/exception is raised? Have a look at your LogCat outupt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which ADT version you used?
If you use ADT 20 then you have to add phonegap jar manually in libs folder then it works.
Please try that and tell me.
And you can also refer my question which I ask and somewhat similar to you..

[Phonegap application stops unexpectedly on Indigo running Android ADT 20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685657/phonegap-application-stops-unexpectedly-on-indigo-running-android-adt-20)

Comment: Hi! thnaks for answer....but i already have libs folder in which i have put phonegap.jar file..

Comment: what does this     options.filter="Bob";  mean?

Comment: if posible than joing with me for this discussion here...http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11300/phonegap

Comment: in res folder you have to create folder xml in which you have to put plugin.xml file which is inside your downloaded phonegap folder....

Comment: It means that it find contact name which name start with Bob or name contain Bob and show all that contacts... You also put there "" which means all contact...