# Phonegap Cordova 2.0.0 fresh install Hello World error

Tags: android, cordova

I have downloaded a fresh copy of Phonegap/Cordova to see why my application continually throws some errors.

I followed the "getting started" from Phonegap and ended up with Hello World working on my device (HTC DesireHD with Android 2.3.3).

So this application does nothing as such, just prints hello world on the device.

The application works which is great however I get some unpleasant error messages in my Logs:

Specifically:

> 09-06 17:26:31.487: E/dalvikvm(32594): Could not find class
>   'android.webkit.WebResourceResponse', referenced from method
>   org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient.generateWebResourceResponse
>   09-06 17:26:31.487: W/dalvikvm(32594): VFY: unable to resolve
>   new-instance 452 (Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;) in
>   Lorg/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient;

I then get other related errors repeating.

I repeat that the application works but I would really like not to see any errors in the logs :-)

Other people have mentioned that it might be due to the name of my libs folder (it is correctly named libs with the `"s"`)

I have included below copies of my `AndroidManifest.xml`, my `MainActivity.java` and the complete `LogCat`.

I am using Win7, Eclipse 3.8.

Thanks very much for any help.

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.qwentes.phonegaptest" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
        <supports-screens  android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
        <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_main" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.qwentes.phonegaptest;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import org.apache.cordova.*;

    public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        }

    }
```

**LogCat.txt**

```
    09-06 17:26:29.265: I/dalvikvm(32594): Could not find method android.webkit.WebView.<init>, referenced from method org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.<init>
    09-06 17:26:29.265: W/dalvikvm(32594): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 3117: Landroid/webkit/WebView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;IZ)V
    09-06 17:26:29.265: D/dalvikvm(32594): VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0001
    09-06 17:26:29.265: D/dalvikvm(32594): VFY: dead code 0x0004-0059 in Lorg/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;IZ)V
    09-06 17:26:29.705: D/Database(32594): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.qwentes.phonegaptest/databases/webview.db, flag = 6, cannot stat file, errno: 2,message: No such file or directory
    09-06 17:26:29.705: D/Database(32594): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.qwentes.phonegaptest/databases/webview.db, mode: delete, disk free size: 554 M, handle: 0x34d960
    09-06 17:26:30.606: V/webviewdatabase(32594): TCP pre connection: creating table in database
    09-06 17:26:30.897: D/Database(32594): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.qwentes.phonegaptest/databases/webviewCache.db, flag = 6, cannot stat file, errno: 2,message: No such file or directory
    09-06 17:26:30.897: D/Database(32594): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.qwentes.phonegaptest/databases/webviewCache.db, mode: delete, disk free size: 554 M, handle: 0x372128
    09-06 17:26:31.467: D/skia(32594): htcFlashPlugin::htcFlashPlugin
    09-06 17:26:31.477: D/qct(32594): [WebView.WebView] >> Enable Shutdown = true
    09-06 17:26:31.477: I/CordovaLog(32594): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
    09-06 17:26:31.477: I/CordovaLog(32594): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=false
    09-06 17:26:31.477: D/CordovaLog(32594): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=false
    09-06 17:26:31.487: E/dalvikvm(32594): Could not find class 'android.webkit.WebResourceResponse', referenced from method org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient.generateWebResourceResponse
    09-06 17:26:31.487: W/dalvikvm(32594): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 452 (Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;) in Lorg/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient;
    09-06 17:26:31.487: D/dalvikvm(32594): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0046
    09-06 17:26:31.487: W/dalvikvm(32594): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;)
    09-06 17:26:31.487: D/dalvikvm(32594): VFY: dead code 0x0048-004c in Lorg/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient;.generateWebResourceResponse (Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;
    09-06 17:26:31.527: W/dalvikvm(32594): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;)
    09-06 17:26:31.527: W/dalvikvm(32594): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;)
    09-06 17:26:31.527: I/dalvikvm(32594): Could not find method android.webkit.WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest, referenced from method org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest
    09-06 17:26:31.527: W/dalvikvm(32594): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3129: Landroid/webkit/WebViewClient;.shouldInterceptRequest (Landroid/webkit/WebView;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;
    09-06 17:26:31.527: D/dalvikvm(32594): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0015
    09-06 17:26:31.527: D/dalvikvm(32594): VFY: dead code 0x0018-0019 in Lorg/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient;.shouldInterceptRequest (Landroid/webkit/WebView;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;
    09-06 17:26:31.527: D/DroidGap(32594): DroidGap.init()
    09-06 17:26:31.547: D/CordovaWebView(32594): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
    09-06 17:26:31.547: D/PluginManager(32594): init()
    09-06 17:26:31.547: D/CordovaWebView(32594): >>> loadUrlNow()
    09-06 17:26:31.587: D/ATRecorder(32594): com.htc.autotest.dlib.RecordEngine in loader dalvik.system.DexClassLoader@4053e810
    09-06 17:26:31.597: D/WindowManagerImpl(32594): addView, new view, mViews[0]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4053ada8
    09-06 17:26:31.597: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(32594): Ignore this event
    09-06 17:26:31.687: W/webcore(32594): Not supported in this case.
    09-06 17:26:31.687: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(32594): Ignore this event
    09-06 17:26:31.817: D/qct(32594): [RequestQueue.ActivePool.ActivePool] >> Enable Shutdown = true
    09-06 17:26:31.817: D/qct(32594): [IdleCache.IdleCache] >> IDLE_CACHE_MAX = 40
    09-06 17:26:32.418: D/DroidGap(32594): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
    09-06 17:26:32.558: D/szipinf(32594): Initializing inflate state
    09-06 17:26:32.558: D/szipinf(32594): Initializing zlib to inflate
    09-06 17:26:32.618: D/webkit-timers(32594): [JWebCoreJavaBridge::resume] >> do resume
    09-06 17:26:32.738: D/dalvikvm(32594): GC_CONCURRENT freed 134K, 44% free 3208K/5639K, external 0K/0K, paused 2ms+20ms
    09-06 17:26:33.729: D/Cordova(32594): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
    09-06 17:26:33.729: D/CordovaWebView(32594): >>> loadUrlNow()
    09-06 17:26:33.729: D/DroidGap(32594): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
    09-06 17:26:33.729: D/DroidGap(32594): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
    09-06 17:26:34.030: I/Database(32594): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at line 27206 of [42537b6056]
    09-06 17:26:34.190: D/DroidGap(32594): onMessage(networkconnection,wifi)
    09-06 17:26:34.230: D/DroidGap(32594): onMessage(spinner,stop)
    09-06 17:26:35.741: D/DroidGap(32594): onMessage(spinner,stop)
    09-06 17:26:44.430: D/dalvikvm(32594): GC_CONCURRENT freed 376K, 46% free 3284K/6023K, external 0K/0K, paused 2ms+3ms
    09-06 17:27:34.619: D/dalvikvm(32594): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 586K, 50% free 3133K/6151K, external 0K/0K, paused 43ms
    09-06 17:28:04.808: D/dalvikvm(32594): GC_CONCURRENT freed 357K, 48% free 3208K/6151K, external 0K/0K, paused 6ms+3ms
```

Comment: I think the answer is here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/11686466/1102741

Best regards.

Comment: Specifically which part of that answer?

Comment: "This issue occurs because the "lib" folder is renamed to "libs" now by Android People. You need to create a libs folder instead of lib and then place your cordova.jar file there. And as soon as we place our external jars to this "libs" folder then it will automatically be added to the build path of the application."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing you can do about those nasty logs in 2.0.0 but they will go away in 2.1.0 which should be out within the week. They are fixed by this commit:

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=incubator-cordova-android.git;a=commit;h=07439ff99ca5f61c444ae7673d9fec96e4502492

Comment: Thanks very much Simon. Looking forward to the new release.

Comment: I have the same issue some one can help me : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839836/salesforce-android-app-remote-access-application-authorization

Comment: I have same issue some one can help me :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839836/salesforce-android-app-remote-access-application-authorization